# microSD card not recognised by lsblk, errors in dmesg

Tags: sd-card, dmesg

I got a new Kingston 1Tb microSD card and made the mistake of putting it into my Steam deck right off rather than formatting it on my laptop first.  The Steam deck format got stuck on "testing" and even though I shut down the device before removing the card, it's now corrupted.

On my Pop!OS laptop, I tried a bunch of things recommended in similar question posts:

- It doesn't show up in the list when I run `lsblk`
- running `dmesg` gives the following errors when I plug in my USB SD card reader (I've used this reader with other microSD cards fine):

```
[71674.229961] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0751, bcdDevice=14.04
[71674.229978] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=0
[71674.229983] usb 2-1: Product: USB Storage
[71674.229987] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: USB Storage
[71674.876426] BPF:     042_EXPECTED_PRESENT type_id=1726 bits_offset=2432
[71674.876434] BPF:  
[71674.876437] BPF: Invalid name
[71674.876438] BPF: 
[71674.876442] failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
[71674.926925] BPF:     042_EXPECTED_PRESENT type_id=1726 bits_offset=2432
[71674.926951] BPF:  
[71674.926955] BPF: Invalid name
[71674.926959] BPF: 
[71674.926965] failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
```

- Because `lsblk` doesn't give me the device name, I can't use `dd` or similar recommendations.
- It doesn't show up in Gparted.

Anything I can do to recover/format the SD card?  I don't care about data loss.

Comment: Where did you buy that SDcard and was it remarkably cheap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Kingston web site](https://www.kingston.com/en/memory-cards?card%20type=microsd) there is no such card with capacity of 1TB. So with very high probability this is a fake card. And the best you can do is to throw it in to the garbage can.

To quoting from [this site](https://photographylife.com/fake-memory-cards):

> Reduced Capacity: Another very common issue, where the card will
> report large capacity to your computer, camera or storage device, when
> in reality it contains only a very small part of the overall capacity.
> For example, a 512 GB SD card might show up as 512 GB on your
> computer, but in reality contain only 16 GB of storage cells. This
> happens because the microchip (a tiny part of the memory card that is
> responsible for reporting the total amount of storage available)
> within the memory card has been reprogrammed to report a different
> size to the host. Such memory cards are extremely dangerous, because
> you might never be able to tell that they are fakes until you start
> filling them up. In this particular case, the first 16 GB of storage
> might work just fine, but anything past that is going to produce data
> errors. Counterfeit memory cards with reduced capacities should be
> avoided the most, because they will most certainly result in data
> loss.

Comment: I think you're right that I've been had.  It wasn't that cheap but I still feel foolish.  Thank you for taking the time to answer.